# Strange behavior with eval in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I try to do is to "eval" the text included in a textarea. The related source code is the following:

```
<script>
 function evaluate() {
     eval(txtarea.value);
 }
</script>

<textarea style="width:90%;" id="txtarea" rows="4" cols="40" /></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Execute" onClick="evaluate()" style="width:120px;">
```

This works in most cases, but not with the following snippet:

```
unescape("alert%28%27ciao%21%27%29%3B")
```

On the other hand, if I include this in the source code, it works without a problem:

```
eval(unescape("alert%28%27ciao%21%27%29%3B"));
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your examples is more like `eval('unescape("alert%28%27ciao%21%27%29%3B")');`

Comment: inception: you need to eval() the results of your eval() to turn the resulting code into action.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! 
@mistapink
Isn't eval supposed to evalute a string argument? What am I missing here?

#dandavis
I actually tried eval(eval(...)) before and it worked indeed. However, I thought that this actually solves the specific problem with the particular example. Will this work reliably with more nested "commands"?

Comment: @Visilios Indeed, it is evaluating a string argument. In your example the value of the text box. So your string is `unescape("alert%28%27ciao%21%27%29%3B")` so eval executes the `unescape` function which produces an unescaped string `alert('ciao!');`. As you mentioned yourself in such particular case you would need a second eval. The more nesting you have the more evals you will have to put.